# Invalid group reference in python 2.7+

Tags: python, regex, django

I am trying to convert all WikiLink type of strings in my webpage(created in django) to html links.

I am using the following expression

```
import re
expr = r'\s+[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+\s'
repl=r'<a href="/photos/\1">\1</a>'
mystr = 'this is a string to Test whether WikiLink will work ProPerly'

parser=re.compile(expr)
parser.sub(repl, mystr)
```

This returns me the following string with hex value replaced for the string.

```
"this is a string to Test whether<a href='/mywiki/\x01>\x01</a>'will work<a href='/mywiki/\x01>\x01</a>'"
```

Looking at the [python help](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for re.sub, I tried changing \1 to \g<1> but that results in a invalid group reference error.

Please help me understand how to get this working

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't have any captured groups in the `expr`.

Whatever part of the match you want to show up as `\1`, you need to put in parentheses. For example:

```
>>> expr = r'\s+([A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+)\s'
>>> parser=re.compile(expr)
>>> parser.sub(repl, mystr)
'this is a string to Test whether<a href="/photos/WikiLink">WikiLink</a>will work ProPerly'
```

The backreference `\1` refers to the group 1 within the match, which is the part that matched the first parenthesized subexpression. Likewise, `\2` is group 2, the part that matched the second parenthesized subexpression, and so on. If you use `\1` when you have fewer than 1 group, some regexp engines will give you an error, others will use a literal `'\1'` character, a ctrl-A; Python does the latter, and the canonical representation of ctrl-A is `'\x01'`, so that's why you see it that way.

Group 0 is the entire match. But that's not what you want in this case, because you don't want the spaces to be part of the substitution.

The only reason you need the `g` syntax is when a simple backreference is ambiguous. For example, if sub were `123\1456`, there's no way to tell whether that means `123`, followed by group 1, followed by `456`, or `123` followed by group 1456, or…

[Further reading on grouping and backreferences.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Adding the paranthesis ( ) solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks to @m.buettner for the great link. If he'd added a comment before editing I would have +1'd it.